How to disable gridviev sorting icon
ı want to disable gridview sorting icon
I want my sort icon to appear only after the first word, but it appears at the end of that title.
  'label' => Html::tag('div', Yii::t('app', 'Create Date'), [
                        'class' => 'text-nowrap text-extra-small text-primary m-0'
                    ]) .
                    Html::tag('div', Yii::t('app', 'Updated Time'), [
                        'class' => 'text-extra-small text-nowrap text-secondary',
                        'style' => 'margin-top: -0.2rem;' // Adjust this value to reduce space between divs
                    ]),

